# Get-AzADApplication : Insufficient privileges to complete the operation

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to add new permissions to the newly created application. I am the owner of the app.
Try it with `az ad app permission add` `Add-AzADAppPermission`.No success, receive that error `Az.MSGraph.internal\Get-AzADApplication : Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.`.
Tried it to add permissions from previously asked questions here and Git Hub, but with no success. [image]

**azure-cli version:2.44.1**

What I'm missing?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the same error as below:***

[image]

Even if the user is the **`owner`** of the Application, *Insufficient privileges* error will still occur:

[image]

> **Note** that: To assign permissions the user account must have **`Application Administrator`** or **`Global Administrator role`**.

**To resolve the error**, I assigned **`Application Administrator`** role to the user account like below:

*Go to Azure AD roles and administrators -> Select Application Administrator -> Add assignments -> Select members -> Select*

[image]

After assigning the role, **I am able to assign API permission to the Azure AD Application** like below:

```
Connect-AzAccount

Add-AzADAppPermission -ObjectId ObjectID -ApiId 00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000 -PermissionId 5f8c59db-677d-491f-a6b8-5f174b11ec1d
```

[image]

The **`Group.Read.All`** API permission added successfully in the Azure Portal like below:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! The problem was that I used to SP id, not the application object id, dummy me... Works as you described in your answer!
Thanks again!